# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'tasks' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Background: I am very new to react.js and I am doing a personal project :D
**UPDATE: Problem solved as I forgot to use the AppProvider component in index.js**
I want to build a home page which loads components based on the content in the local storage, but I keep getting the error as shown above.

Here is my context.js code:

```
import React, {useState,useContext,useEffect} from "react"
const AppContext = React.createContext()

const AppProvider =  ({children}) =>{
    const [tasks,setTasks] = useState([])
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)

    const getLocalStorage = () =>{
        let stuff = localStorage.getItem("tasks")
        if(stuff){
          return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
        }
        else{
          return []
        }
      }
      const fetchData = async()=>{
        setLoading(true)
        setTasks(getLocalStorage());
        setLoading(false);
      }
      useEffect(()=>{
          fetchData()
      })

      useEffect(()=>{
        localStorage.setItem("tasks",JSON.stringify(tasks))
      },[tasks])


return <AppContext.Provider
value = {{
    loading,
    tasks,setTasks,

}}>
    {children}
</AppContext.Provider>
}


export const useGlobalContext = () =>{
    return useContext(AppContext)
}
export {AppContext,AppProvider}
```

Here is my Home.js

```
import TaskNode from "../components/taskNode";
import NewTask from "../components/newTask";
import {useGlobalContext} from "../context";

const Home = () =>{
    const {tasks} = useGlobalContext();
   
    return(<div id = "home">
        {
tasks.map((task)=>{
//return <TaskNode key = {task.id}{...task}/>
})
        }
    {/* <TaskNode/>
    <TaskNode/> */}
    <NewTask/>
    
    </div>)

}
export default Home;
```

Thks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem lays with `<AppContext.Provider>`, should it be `value={}` instead of `value={{}}`

Comment: Are you wrapping `Home`(or a parent) in `AppProvider`? Something like `<AppProvider><Home/></AppProvider>`

@axtck That's not the problem, it's the way of writing a js expression in jsx

Comment: @Fdr, im using react routers though.

Comment: Update: solved. thks guys! i realised i forgot to use the AppProvider component in my index.js